# Which Should i use for communication of android and a php

Tags: android

Iam making an location app in android, i want to send the user location data to server and also server can send data to user apllication. which should i use soap or rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your services are resource oriented (i.e. you can express them as CRUD operations over a set of entities), then use REST. If your services are method oriented, and you need a rigid interface contract, use SOAP.

Comment: i didnt understand in my situation my app with the specified time interval send user location to server and server perform some calculation and  send data to application.

Comment: i want server take a string type of data in http request and store it in database and apply some calculation and send notification to user